# Type not found on XAML namespace

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, namespaces

I am trying to access to method class from XAML file.

My class is on folder: project.Utils.

Adding on xaml Content Page:

```
xmlns:local="project.Utils"
```

I try to use `myConverterMethod` class inside Utils folder and use it as:

```
Converter={StaticResource myConverterMethod}
```

but `error  Type myConverterMethod not found in xmlns project.Utils`.

Where is my fault?

Comment: try this `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:project.Utils`. Here project name is project & folder name inside shared project is "Utils"

Comment: Are you sure that the class `myConverterMethod` is in the _namespace_ `project.Utils`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:project.Utils;assembly=project"
```

Comment: Same "StaticResource not found for key myConverterMethod" crash

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to refer to a `Method` within a specific class but to a `IValueConverter`.

In order to achieve what you want, you need to define a class that implements `IValueConverter`:

```
public class IntToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value != 0;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Define the created converter in accessible scope: Page/View or Application. By scope I mean resources:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:IntToBoolConverter x:Key="intToBool" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

and finally consume the converter in the next way:

```
<Button Text="Search"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Reference entry1},
    Path=Text.Length,
    Converter={StaticResource intToBool}}" />
```

Xamarin has a very nice [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) that will answer all your questions and it  usually has a good code samples.